# Cake Web Deployment Issue

Tags: webdeploy, cakebuild

Working on web deployment(http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.WebDeploy/).

Faced the below issue

**An error occurred when executing task 'Deploy'.
Error: Could not connect to the remote computer ("net1-7103"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.**

**Note:** Web management service is started and Web deploy is also installed

***Machine details***:Windows 10 64 bit
here is my code

```
Task("Deploy")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Description("Deploy build website")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        DeployWebsite(new DeploySettings()
        {
            SourcePath = "./Examplesite/obj/Release/Package/Examplesite.CI.MVCApp.zip",
            SiteName = "BuildAuto",
            Port=8082,
            ComputerName = "NET1-7103",
            Username = "labuser",
            Password = "*****"

        });
    });

Task("build")
    .IsDependentOn("Restore-NuGet-Packages")
    .Does(() =>
{    
    try {
        MSBuild(currentDirectoryAppInfo + @"\Examplesite.CI.MVCApp.sln",  new MSBuildSettings()
        .SetConfiguration(configuration)
        .WithProperty("DeployOnBuild","true")
        .SetVerbosity(Verbosity.Minimal));

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {        
        buildStatus = false;
    }
```

Comment: Try to use IP-address instead of NetBios-name.

Comment: Allow incoming connections for Web Management Service through the target machine firewall (port 8082).